# get string from txt file on vb.net

Tags: vb.net

hi i have problem in my code, i just want to call a .txt file insert into  my table database but i can not find the functional at all
it my .txt file

"101772"|"CS101772039001567"|"28012015"|"101772039"|"83521318"|"CJVAN02"
"101772"|"CS101772039001567"|"28012015"|"101772039"|"83521318"|"CJVAN02"
"101772"|"CS101772039001567"|"28012015"|"101772039"|"83521318"|"CJVAN02"

where | is an end of field, i can call the txt file, but not to call one by one of string and insert into database, can any one help me with this one? thanks.

Comment: Feed all the lines into an array. For each element in the array, split on `|`. I think that should be more than enough to get you started.

Comment: hmm.. can you give me sample code? @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ

Comment: There are plenty of example of how to read a text file in VB.Net on the internet.

Comment: no i mean index one by one string from the .txt @BlackFrog

Comment: I don't understand? Are you having issues inserting the string into the database? Or are you having issues reading the text file?

Comment: Show your code what you have tried so far and describe the actual problem you have in detail

Comment: nope gays i get from @kiLLua, after all i wanted for call it one by one like spit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that you can read your .txt file but cannot call it one by one?
read it as string then split it one by one.
Here: You can split your input

```
Public Class Form1

Dim input As String = "101772|CS101772039001567|28012015|101772039|83521318|CJVAN02"

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim delimiter As Char = "|"
    Dim substrings() As String = input.Split(delimiter)

    For Each substring In substrings
        Console.WriteLine(substring)
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

This is just a little tip. you can start it from here.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class with the properties having all the columns fields that you require to insert a single row into the table.
Store all the records in the txt file as a list of that class and then insert all the records at once to the database.